# How to extract filename from path using sed or awk

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

I am trying to parse a filename from a modified apache web access log entry that is tab delimited:

```
/common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif    /common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif   03/Dec/2012:00:00:00    127.0.0.1   03/Dec/2012:00:00:00    us   404
```

I would like it to come out like this:

```
klArrowRight.gif    /common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif   03/Dec/2012:00:00:00    127.0.0.1   03/Dec/2012:00:00:00    us   404
```

I have tried something like this in [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

> 's:.*/::'

However, it is too greedy, and it eats the rest of my line. I have been looking through posts, but so far no luck.  Any hints?

Comment: so you want everything except for the path to the file, correct?

Comment: @begemotv2718, `basename` will give the name of the script in **in which basename is executed**

Comment: @foampile Excerpted from `basename` manual page - `basename NAME` ... `Print NAME with any leading directory components removed`. Doesn't have anything to do with the script in which `basename` is executed. Maybe you have a different version?

Comment: i stand corrected.  thanks

Comment: @foampile: not exactly 
cat /tmp/log.txt | awk '{ "basename " $1 | getline x; print x " " $2 " " $3 " ";}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the input/output in your question is not well formatted. do you need this?

```
awk '{gsub(/\/.*\//,"",$1); print}' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "/common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif /common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif 03/Dec/2012:00:00:00 127.0.0.1 03/Dec/2012:00:00:00 us 404"|awk '{gsub(/\/.*\//,"",$1); print}'
```

output:

```
klArrowRight.gif /common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif 03/Dec/2012:00:00:00 127.0.0.1 03/Dec/2012:00:00:00 us 404
```

Comment: Ok, all good suggestions! I of course found the answer as I was about to give up.

I used a form like:

awk '{ n=split($4,a,"/"); print a[n], "\t", $4, "\t", $3, "\t", $2, "\t", $3, "\t", $1, "\t", $5 }'

which in my case solved it for me.

I also checked awk '{gsub(//.*//,"",$1); print}' which also solved my problem.

The perl solution looked good too, but wanted to avoid using this in the context of my particular problem.

Comment: The RE posted above is a bit more complicated than it needs to be and this is a job for sub(), not gsub(). gsub() will work too but it's overkill and misleading since you just want to do the substition once. It will also convert all the tabs delimiting the fields in your file into spaces which could cause problems if you have spaces in your file names or empty fields.

Comment: @MarkMcWhirter and don't do `awk '{ n=split($4,a,"/"); print a[n], "\t", $4, "\t", $3, "\t", $2, "\t", $3, "\t", $1, "\t", $5 }'`, like you mentioned in your comment as that's wrong in so many ways...

Answer (score 8):

None of the given answers seem to be correct completely when only the extraction of a filename from a given absolute path is desired. Therefore I give here the solution.
Let's consider in variable *filename* we have the complete path, e.g., *filename=/ABC/DEF/GHI*
Then,

```
echo $filename | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print $NF}'
```

will result in the filename *GHI*.

Comment: Correct because the question specifically mentions sed or awk. But a simpler way to do this is just: file_only=$(basename $filename) which will give you GHI in $file_only.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this pretty easily with just sed, as long as you tell it not to be too greedy:

```
% echo '/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif 03/Dec/2012' | sed 's,^[^ ]*/,,'
klArrowRight.gif 03/Dec/2012
%
```

(that is, "starting at the beginning of the line, find the longest-possible list of non-space characters, followed by a slash")

Answer (score 2):

using perl regexp and basename (i not think you stuck on sed/awk):

```
perl -p -e 'use File::Basename;s/([^\s]+\s+)[^\s]+\s+/$1/;print basename($1)'
```

example:

```
echo "/common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif /common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif 03/Dec/2012:00:00:00 127.0.0.1 03/Dec/2012:00:00:00 us 404" |
   perl -p -e 'use File::Basename;s/([^\s]+\s+)[^\s]+\s+/$1/;print basename($1)'

klArrowRight.gif /common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif 03/Dec/2012:00:00:00 127.0.0.1 03/Dec/2012:00:00:00 us 404
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/.*\//,"",$1)} 1' file
```

Comment: I'm using cygwin, and getting a syntax error at the closing brace.

Comment: it was missing the closing ")" for ths sub() function. I updated my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU grep`:

```
grep -oP "[^/]*\t.*" file
```

Results:

```
klArrowRight.gif    /common/common/img/pictos/klArrowRight.gif  03/Dec/2012:00:00:00    127.0.0.1   03/Dec/2012:00:00:00    us  404
```